# left join with correct total sum, after count and sum challenge

Tags: sql

I have a query that I seem to be stuck on and I am not sure how to solve the issue. It is only section midway down the query that is throwing me off. I just want to count and sum up the total cost of a field using a left join and have the total sum be correct. I believe the issue is that if there are more than 1 item related to that account on the same table, it will sum up multiple times and the total sum will then not be correct. Here is the section that i and struggling with....

```
left join  
(select distinct (soid), count(*) as oaccount, sum( amount) as c3 from
 soorderdetails  where soorderdetails.description like 'Installation%' or 
 soorderdetails.description like 'Training%'  or soorderdetails.description 
 like 'Fusion Report%' group by soid) as o  on o.soid=s.soid


 The result I would like to obtain is:
  Job#  | (c3) | Soid
  ----- | -----|-----
   223  | 2000 | 212 (1 record - c3 amount - 1=2000)
   224  | 300  | 213 (2 record - c3 amount - 1=100 + 2=200)
   225  | 4333 | 214 (1 record - c3 amount - 1=4333)
   226  | 1000 | 215 (3 record - c3 amount - 1=200 + 2=300 + 3=500)

  But I am getting this....

  Job# | (c3) | Soid
  -----| -----|-----
  223  | 2000 | 212 (1 record...sum is correct here)
  224  | 600  | 213 (2 record - 1=100x2 + 2=200x2)=WRONG
  225  | 4333 | 214 (1 record...sum is correct here)
  226  | 2500 | 215 (3 record - 1=200x3 + 2=300x3 + 3=500x3)=WRONG
```

What I'm looking for is to display all distinct(soid) record along with the total sum of the (c3) field for each distinct(soid) record.

So with the query above, I can see the sum of C3 displayed. If there is only 1 record the sum is displayed correctly, if there are more than 1 records, the number of record is getting multiplied by the number of soid match found and then added together throwing off the total sum value. I have tried to adopt some of the solutions found here but still can't get it to display correctly. Would anyone be able to help? Thank you in advanced!

- Table 1 has a matching soid id field (s.soid)
- Table 2 has the soid, description and amount field (o.soid)
- I am trying to left join table 2 to table 1 by using the soid field.
- I would like to sum the amount field properly. Right now it seems that every 'amount' sum is being multiplied by the count number found for that record. Thank you!

Here is the full query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT (jobnumber) as l1,
                c2 as l2, 
                sum(isnull(c3,0)) as l3, 
                sum((isnull(c3,0)/150)*50) as l4, 
                sum(c5) as l5, sum(c6) as l6,sum(c5+c6) as l7, 
                sum(c5*25.27) as l8,
                isnull(c9,0) as l9,
                (sum(c5*25.27)+(isnull(c9,0))) as l10, 
                sum((isnull(c3,0)/150)*50)-(sum(c5*25.27)
                                       +(isnull(c9,0))) as l11 ,  
                sum(isnull(c3,0))-(sum(c5*25.27)+(isnull(c9,0))) as l12   
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT (j.jobnumber),  
                      customername as c2,
                      c3, 
                      c5,
                      c6, 
                      c9 
      FROM dbo.SOOrders as s 
      LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT DISTINCT (jobid),
                                  COUNT(*) as s9, 
                                  sum(total) as c9  
                 FROM apvouchers 
                 GROUP BY jobid
                 ) as v ON v.jobid = s.jobid  
      LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT DISTINCT (soid), 
                                  COUNT(*) as oaccount, 
                                  SUM(amount) as c3 
                 FROM soorderdetails  
                 WHERE description LIKE 'Installation%' 
                    OR description LIKE 'Training%'  
                    OR description LIKE 'Fusion Report%' 
                 GROUP BY soid
                 ) as o ON o.soid = s.soid   
      INNER JOIN sccalls as t ON t.jobid = s.jobid  
      INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT DISTINCT(callid),   
                                  COUNT(*) as myaccount,
                                  SUM(actualhours) as c5,
                                  SUM(overtimehours) as c6 
                  FROM scqreportlabors 
                  WHERE actualhours > 0 
                  GROUP BY callid
                 ) as r ON r.callid = t.callid  
      LEFT JOIN ShAgents ON AgentID = TechnicianID   
      LEFT JOIN arcustomers as c ON c.customerid = s.customerid   
      INNER JOIN icjobs as j ON j.jobid = s.jobid 
      WHERE j.active = 1
     ) as x 
GROUP BY jobnumber, c2, c9 
ORDER BY jobnumber DESC
```

Comment: please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: What results do you get when you only run the subquery against the `soorderdetails` table? Does the c3 return what is expected? If your problem exists within the subquery then it has nothing to do with your `LEFT JOIN` as everything within the parentheses you have shown is self-contained. A problem subquery would suggest that you either don't understand what is stored in the `amount` field or you have a normalization problem with that table.

Comment: I have updated the post so you can see the full query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things going on here...

You don't need `DISTINCT` (in your *main* select) and a `GROUP BY`, it's redundant.  The grouping will already make the records distinct:

```
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT soid, COUNT(*) as oaccount, SUM(amount) as c3 
   FROM  soorderdetails  
   WHERE soorderdetails.description like 'Installation%' 
   OR    soorderdetails.description like 'Training%'  
   OR    soorderdetails.description like 'Fusion Report%' 
   GROUP BY soid
 ) AS o ON o.soid = s.soid
```

What I think you were going for, is the equivalent of adding the `DISTINCT` modifier to your `SUM(amount)` to only sum unique values `SUM(DISTINCT amount)`:

```
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT soid, COUNT(*) as oaccount, SUM(DISTINCT amount) as c3 
   FROM  soorderdetails  
   WHERE soorderdetails.description like 'Installation%' 
   OR    soorderdetails.description like 'Training%'  
   OR    soorderdetails.description like 'Fusion Report%' 
   GROUP BY soid
 ) AS o ON o.soid = s.soid
```

That all said... Based on this:

> however if there are more than one record, the 'amount' gets
>   multiplied by the number of records

I'm guessing you don't want the sum at all:

```
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT soid, COUNT(*) as oaccount, amount as c3 
   FROM  soorderdetails  
   WHERE soorderdetails.description like 'Installation%' 
   OR    soorderdetails.description like 'Training%'  
   OR    soorderdetails.description like 'Fusion Report%' 
   GROUP BY soid, amount
 ) AS o ON o.soid = s.soid
```

Which would be great, because `SUM(DISTINCT..`) operations really destroy performance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and examples. I appreciate you spending the time to look at it. I may have explained it wrong in the beginning but I think i have now updated the information I am looking for correctly. I would like the actual sum but not have multiple records showing as the queries suggested above does, I think the new revision of what I was aiming for is better explained now. Thanks again and any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: @Missingsiam No problem.  If you run just the inner select (derived table) part of this left join, do you still get the wrong `SUM(amount)`?  Or is it only wrong once you run the main query?

Comment: @Missingsiam I won't be available again until tomorrow, but basically one of two things is happening.  If you try my previous comment, and run the inner select, and the values are duplicated, then change it to `SUM(DISTINCT amount)` to fix that table duplication.  If the values are correct, then something in your main query is causing the duplication, so we will have to look at the whole thing. :D

Comment: Thanks Aaron. All 3 of your suggestions resulted in the same results as I already have. It still did not correctly SUM C3 properly. The result of C3 is actually getting multiplied instead of being added together by the count field. I updated my post to try to further explain what is happening and what i would like to achieve. I

Comment: @Missingsiam It's tough to tell where the duplication is without seeing the schema, but if none of my suggestions worked, then it must be happening in the main query.  I'd venture a guess that if change this `sum(isnull(c3,0)) as l3` to this `sum(distinct isnull(c3,0)) as l3` that it will work, but you should really remove all of the sums, and add a `WHERE jobnumber = 'any single job number'` so that you can see what is happening and know how to fix it.

Comment: @Missingsiam Also to reiterate this... `SELECT DISTINCT` does the same thing as `SELECT....GROUP BY`, so you only need one or the other.  Also you don't need the `()` around the first column after `DISTINCT`.  `DISTINCT` is a modifier, not a function, and it affects all columns in your select.  The only way to use it on a single column is through a subquery or a function, like my `SUM(DISTINCT column)` suggestion here. :)

Comment: Hey Aaron...I think the previous suggestion may be the right one. I will check all the records to see if it is. You suggested changing the sum(isnull(c3,0)) as l3 to this sum(distinct isnull(c3,0)) as l3...

Comment: @Missingsiam Cool, I hope that does it

Comment: Thank you Aaron that did the trick. I used one too many sum() and it kept multiplying so the results got skewed. I appreciate the time you spent on helping me solve the mystery.